# Requiring a child that accepts a ref attribute in React + Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using React + Typescript, I'd like to create a `children` prop that only accepts a single child that accepts a understands and accepts a `ref` attribute. Basically, my children type should accept:

- an instance of a React class component
- a standard React HTML element (e.g. `<button>`, `<div>`)
- a `forwardRef` wrapped function component

It should not accept:

- a regular function component
- a text node, like a string or number

My goal with this `children` type is to inject a ref into the child using `React.cloneElement` with some level of certainty that `ref` will not go completely ignored.

I have tried

```js
import React from "react";

type Props = {
    // EDIT: This is how I originally typed `children` to
    // get a decent compile time check that returns errors
    // if the children is a text node or multiple elements.
    // The same effect can be achieved with the `ReactElement` type.
    // children: React.FunctionComponentElement<React.RefAttributes<HTMLElement>>;
    children: React.ReactElement;
};

const MyComponent = (props: Props) => {
    const childRef = React.useRef(null);

    const child = React.Children.only(props.children);
    if (!React.isValidElement(child)) {
        return props.children;
    }
    return React.cloneElement(child, {ref: childRef});
};
```

This compiles, and `MyComponent` not accept text nodes as children, but it does accept non `forwardRef` function components without complaint.

```js
// This fails with an error that a text node is not a valid child.
<MyComponent>hello</MyComponent>

// This compiles without issue, but should fail because MyText is not a `forwardRef` component.
const MyText = () => <span>hello</span>;
<MyComponent><MyText/></MyComponent>
```

I've also tried some other types, but this feels like the closest I've gotten.

Is creating a type requirement like this possible with Typescript? If so, how can it be done?

Comment: unfortunately, I didn't find the answer yet.  

Did find a runtime function in react-is - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-is `isForwardRef` that seems to return the correct answer

Comment: @Alissa Thanks for the note. Checking at runtime is obviously not ideal, but it's a whole lot better than nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

There is no way to enforce that an instance of a React component is utilizing `React.forwardRef()`. That's because React doesn't preserve the type of the original function or class a component instance was created with. An instance of a React component in JSX will always be `JSX.Element`, `React.FunctionComponentElement<...>`, or `React.CElement<...>`.

Example:

```js
const MyForwardedRefComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement>((props, ref) => {
  return <div ref={ref}>{props.children}</div>;
});

// JSX.Element
const myInstance = <MyForwardedRefComponent />;

// React.FunctionComponentElement<{}>
const myOtherInstance = React.createElement(MyForwardedRefComponent);
```

However, you *can* enforce that a React component only accepts a single child element, and TypeScript will warn you accordingly. This is about as good as you can hope for you in your case.

Example:

```js
const SingleChildOnly: React.FC<{ children: React.ReactElement }> = ({
  children,
}) => {
  const ref = React.useRef(null);
  const child = React.Children.only(children);

  return React.cloneElement(child, { ref });
};

const thisIsOkay = (
  <SingleChildOnly>
    <div>hello</div>
  </SingleChildOnly>
);

// error
const thisIsNotOkay = (
  <SingleChildOnly>
    <div>hello</div>
    <div>hello there</div>
  </SingleChildOnly>
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation + advice. It looks like using `ReactElement` as the `children` type gives me the same compile time errors as my `FunctionComponentElement<RefAttributes<HTMLElement>>` thing, but is more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

I also couldn't find a typescript solution for this.

What I wanted to do is create a Tooltip component to wrap other components with.

The best I can come up with so far, is writing the SingleChildOnly component as a custom hook which will return: a reference to put on the child, any props to add to the child and the Element you want to render.

This way you can force the child component to be able to accept a ref.

The downside is that you need to write much more code when using the SingleChildOnly component.

I thought of creating `TextWithTooltip` `ButtonWithTooltip` base components wrapping only a simple html span or button.

Don't know if it's applicable for your use case